# Swapfile mount (/etc/fstab): "swap swap" or "none swap"

Tags: mount, swap, fstab

There seems to be conflicting information on how to mount a swapfile.

[`swap swap`](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04/):

[image]

[`none swap`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04):

[image]

[both](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/setting_up_swap.html):

[image]

Both ways work. **What is the official recommendation and how does each way affect swapping?**

Comment: You can use swap partitions; or swapfiles.  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and later default to swapfiles, but systems installed before then will have swap partitions. Each has pros & cons, depending on your use.  Ubuntu 16.04 LTS used swap partitions by default, my current system uses both.  Swap partition requires the size to be set at or before install time (ie. plan ahead & more difficult to change). However my system dual boots (19.10 & 18.04) so both Ubuntu's can share the swap partition thus not wasting space. Your use case will dictate best for you.

Comment: @guiverc I use files. the last example uses partitions, but the first two use files (`fallocate -l 1G /swapfile`) and diverge on the mount.

Comment: Regarding your first question (swap swap vs none swap) - the man pages associated with 19.04 indicate the proper option for Ubuntu is "none swap"